# Math extension installation for Mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki

I am trying to enable my Mediawiki 1.28 to handle math equations. I followed the instructions given [here](http://www.andersen.one/install-math-extension-mediawiki/), [here](https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/mediawiki/mediawiki_math.htm) and [here](https://www.siteground.com/kb/how_to_enable_math_support_in_my_mediawiki_application/).

However, when I write the following in a page on my Mediawiki, it does not get rendered:

```
<math>x=\frac{-b+\sqrt{d}}{2*a}</math>
```

My PHP version is 7.0.14. I do not know if I am doing anything wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is your extension listed in _Special:Version_?

Comment: Yes it is listed.

Comment: Please be more specific. What does "not get rendered" mean? Also, check the [error logs](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:How_to_debug#Logging).

Comment: Means it does not get converted into math symbols, it shows the same, i.e. <math>x=\frac{-b+\sqrt{d}}{2*a}</math> on the page.